# Changing <html lang> in SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

how can I change the

```
 <html lang="en">
```

to

```
 <html lang="de">
```

with svelteKit? I build static pages:

```
 export default {
 kit: {
  adapter: adapter({
  // default options are shown
  pages: 'build',
  assets: 'build',
  fallback: '404.html',
  precompress: false
}),

prerender: {
  // This can be false if you're using a fallback (i.e. SPA mode)
  default: true
}
}
};
```

thanks for help

Comment: Do you mean change it dynamically or just change it for the whole project and have it baked out with your static pages?

Comment: I mean change it for the whole project, baked out with the static pages

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's static for the whole project, you can edit it in your `app.html` file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        %sveltekit.head%
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>%sveltekit.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks! (i am in the svelte learning phase;-)